# cellForRowAtIndexPath never called in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called (numberOfRowsInSection is) using UITableViewController with the following way:

```
import UIKit
import EventKit

class EventThisWeekController: UITableViewController {

    var eventStore: EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
    var eventsThisWeek: [EKEvent] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event) {
            (granted, error) -> Void in

            guard granted else { fatalError("Permission denied") }

            let endDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800)
            let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(NSDate(),
                                                                            endDate: endDate,
                                                                            calendars: nil)
            self.eventsThisWeek = self.eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate)
            print(self.eventsThisWeek.count)
        }

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellForRowAtIndexPath")
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.eventsThisWeek[indexPath.row].title

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("numberOfRowsInSection")
        return eventsThisWeek.count
    }
}
```

Data source and delegate is assigned to this Controller and EvenThisWeekController is a class designed in main storyboard. As result, in my app table is displayed without any result. Of course, eventThisWeek  array length is not equal to 0. Any ideas how I can solve it?

Comment: Did you set the subclass of the controller in the storyboard? Also, did you add a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` to the storyboard?

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, I set EventThisWeekController in *Custom class* section and the controller that I have used in storyboard is UITableViewController

Comment: Is the numberOfRows method called?

Comment: You need to reload the tableView when you finally get some value in your result array.
write self.tableView.reloadData() below the last line of assigning some value to self.eventsThisWeek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code in viewDidLoad with this.

```
self.eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event) {
    (granted, error) -> Void in

    guard granted else { fatalError("Permission denied") }

    let endDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604800)
    let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(NSDate(),
                                                                    endDate: endDate,
                                                                    calendars: nil)
    self.eventsThisWeek = self.eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
    print(self.eventsThisWeek.count)
 }
```

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't call because when your view is loaded at that time array was empty and when the self.eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType is completely executed and load array with new value you weren't notifying your tableView to reload the data as you have new values in your array.

Comment: @jgd Please read the description below so that you can understand what was the actual problem.

Comment: Ah, well spotted :)

Comment: This answer has a few issues. 1) You must call `reloadData` on the main queue. This completion handler will be called on a background queue. 2) Do not treat denial as a fatal error. Real users will deny access or restrictions may prevent access. Handle those case properly, not by deliberately crashing the app.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you sir for correcting me. I will keep it in my mind.

Comment: The syntax for `dispatch_async` doesn't look right and you still treat "permission denied" as a fatal error. That's a really poor user experience.

Comment: Can you please comment the correct syntax so that i can save my self next time.